# How to find overlapping / redundant nodes in a tree

Tags: c#, asp.net, algorithm, tree

I have a list of nodes in a big hierarchy. How do I efficiently determine which of my nodes are descendants of any others in my list?

Specifically this is a list of ASP.NET controls. My code examines each of these nodes and their descendants, so I am trying to eliminate redundancy.

A simple example is this tree:

```
         Parent
         /    \
    Gladis    Arthur
    /    \
 Jon      Sam
```

My list contains `{ Parent, Jon }`.

I would like to write an algorithm that reduces the list to just `Parent` based on the fact that the `Parent` node contains `Jon` as a descendant.

Here is code:

```
    public class Node
    {
        public Node(string name_, params Node[] children_)
        {
            this.children = children_;
        }
        public string name;
        public Node[] children;
    }

    public class NodeAnalysis
    {
        public Node node;
        public Node containingAncestor = null;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Node jon = new Node("jon");
        Node parent = new Node("parent",
            new Node("Gladis",
                jon,
                new Node("Sam")),
            new Node("Arthur")
        );

        List<NodeAnalysis> results = new List<NodeAnalysis>();
        results.Add(new NodeAnalysis{ node = parent });
        results.Add(new NodeAnalysis{ node = jon });

        foreach (NodeAnalysis item in results)
        {
            // ??? populate item.containingAncestor
        }
    }
```

I can't think of an efficient algorithm to accomplish this. I cannot control the order in which the nodes are added to the list. It seems like it could be optimized by examining both the tree and the relationships I've already identified in the list as I traverse it.

**EDIT: `.parent` is available in the `Node` struct. It's easier to discover ancestral relationship using `.parent`.

Comment: How can you detect whether node A is a parent for node B? with `A.Controls.Contains(B)`?

Comment: Define "efficient".  How efficient does it actually need to be?  Try using an inefficient naive approach and see if it's actually too slow or not.

Comment: Just "reasonably efficient". In the same way you might choose quicksort over bubble sort. I can tell for example that I have to choose whether it's best to enumerate over my `results` list, or the tree. My spidy sense says enumerating over the tree is more efficient...

Comment: @tenfour it most likely depends on how big the results list is, and whether it contains any items that are high in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
public static void RemoveDescendants(IList<Node> list)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < list.Count; index++)
        RemoveDescendants(list[index], list);
}
private static void RemoveDescendants(Node node, IList<Node> list)
{
    foreach (var child in node.children)
    {
        list.Remove(child);
        RemoveDescendants(child, list);
    }
}
```